# Android release apk with Cocos2d-js

Tags: android, build, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm facing problems to build a release version for android.
I runned the command:

```
cocos compile -p android -m release
```

And it's returning the following error message:

```
Error running command, return code: 2. Check the log file at /home/felipesaruhashi/.cocos2d/cocos2d.log

Error running command, return code: 1
```

In the log file:

```
 ~/cocos2d-js-v3.0/tools/cocos2d-console/bin/../plugins/plugin_jscompile/bin/jsbcc: 1: ~/cocos2d-js-v3.0/tools/cocos2d-console/bin/../plugins/plugin_jscompile/bin/jsbcc: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

I'm on linux(ubuntu 14.04 lts and cocos2d-js 3.0) by the way.

Comment: That is most strange indeed.. Are you using latest version? Not many community (cocos2d's) members use linux sadly, so it may be a platform specific problem.. I'd advice [creating a bug report in github](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js/issues) or a post in the official forums.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, i already posted on the forum with no answer so far... I posted a issue also... Everything else on linux it's working fine, just the release part i will use anther OS, thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it seems that there is no jsbcc linux support, though there is a [merge request](https://github.com/cocos2d-html5/JSCompiler/pull/2).

edit: The MR has been accepted.